# How to open a Vida shower faucet valve faceplate

Tags: shower, plumbing-fixture

I have a Vida brand shower faucet, and I am need of opening the main valve for some work .. however, I cannot for the life of me remember how I got it off in the past (years ago).

Hoping somebody can help shed some light.

I've tried alan key, long thin flat head screwdriver ... I know there's something I have to do with this back socket "thing" (either unscrew, or pressure release?) but I also don't want to force it (I know it's easy once it's done right . I recall that much).

Does anyone have any ideas ?

[image: Front view]
[image: Brand Logo]
[image: Socket]

Comment: I'm guessing a hex key (sae or metric) to get the grub screw loose in the handle; pull the handle; then see what you've got.

Comment: I've tried every size hex key I could, nothing seems to grab purchase in there .. I tried grabbing the best pic I could .. .sorry for the flash, but that's the best I could get. :(

Comment: Try a small flat blade screwdriver….

Comment: same problem .. as I mentioned in original post, tried both alan key, and flat head screwdiver .. can't seem to get purchase on anything .. so not sure if it's a rotation thing, or spring/pressure switch.

Comment: Oops, sorry: I missed the screwdriver reference in your original text.

Comment: Ok .. update .. I fiddled with it again today.  Turns out I had managed (at some point) to remove the set screw. And with that, I was able to confirm which size allen key did the job.   Ok, so set screw is out (and yes, I can and have put it back in as well) .. but regardless of how loose it is, the handle still doesn't come off .. I recall it just sliding off once this screw was removed .. but I guess I"m missing another step?  (I've tried to remove the "ping handle" on the knob, but it won't budge either).
I have the docs for it, but they are unhelpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just pull on it. Once the set screw is removed, it will pull away from the wall. The problem is that its likely very stuck due to buildup. I had to rotate mine to full cold so that set screw hole could point up, and kept pouring vinegar in there over a period of a few hours, every 15 min or so. I tried to grab onto it with my hands while wearing rubber gloves, and gently (very gently) rock it up/down while pulling it away from the wall. It didn't work. I then took a plastic card, placed it under the piece and used a flat head screwdriver wedged between the faceplate (protected by the plastic card not to scratch it) and the round handle. The handle took some slight damage from screw driver but it came off. (basically I put flat head screw driver at the bottom of the knob where I could damage it so it would not be visible, then tried to pry it off).
I have that same temperature selector but with a 3 way shower valve. I hate that thing, had to take it apart a few times now.

Adding the photos of how it looked like taken apart, hope they help a bit. Oh and that other chrome ring that you see around the cartridge... It got super stuck, I had to cut it off and replace with a new one. That piece simply gets screwed onto the assembly, and I guess should not be super tight, except king kong himself tightened mine when he installed this shower, so I had no choice but to cut it off.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Ok, thank you .. I'll try some of those things ... I "thought" it was just "pull" at that point, but wasn't 100% sure, thank you for confirming.  Also thanks for your pic, as it shows that little pin still in, so no need to remove it (didn't think so . again, needed confirmation).   I'll try again next weekend when I have time and update :)   But thanks, should work with some ... "elbow grease" I suspect now :)

Comment: Ok .. *finally* got to it .. and having had the verification you gave of "just yank it!" ;)  I got a couple old credit cards like you suggested (helpful, neat trick! ty), and got my screwdiver in there and "wiggled" ... took a good 5 min or so .. just wiggle wiggle ... :)  but that sucker ever slow slowly inched off ... Fixed up what I was after, put everything back, re-caulked, good as new!!   Thank you again so much!